# Linking multiple TraceSource events with CorrelationManager

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, asp.net-web-api, system.diagnostics

I am developing a web service in C# with .NET WebAPI and I would like to log multiple events for every request, into Windows event log.  Since the service runs in a multithreaded model and will receive hundreds or requests per second, I need to be able to group log entries by requests, so that I can see all the entries for a failed request for example.

The plan is to generate a unique Id (Guid) for every request and log event with a severity level (Verbose/Information/Error/Warning/Critical) including the Id in every log entry, so that I can group the events.

After trying with NLog, I started looking into *System.Diagnostics.TraceSource* in combination with *System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId*, following articles found online, many here on SO.  Logging works but I'm stuck on two problems.

My web.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="My.App" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
      <listeners>
        <add name="eventlogListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="eventlogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="MyAppCategory" />
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**Problem 1**

- If I use *TraceTransfer* I can specify the ActivityId (which is
  automatically appended to the message) but I cannot specify the event level (e.g.
  TraceEventType.Error)
- If I use *TraceEvent* I can specify the level but not the ActivityId, and the Activity Id does not appear anywhere

Is there a way to have both level and activity id in a log event ?

**Problem 2**

I would like to see the ActivityId in the "Correlation Id" column of the event viewer, so that I can group events.  I've seen some applications storing a Guid there, but I haven't found any documentation on how to achieve the same in C#/.NET.  I noticed that *TraceEvent* accepts a *object[] args* parameter, for which I have not found any example though.

Could anyone point me to some docs or provide a working example ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Add the `traceOutputOptions` attribute to your `eventlogListener`definition:

`traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack"`

The resulting element will be:

```
<add name="eventlogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="MyAppCategory" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack"/>
```

The resulting output will be quite similar to this:

```
testtrace Start: 0 : Main task started
    LogicalOperationStack=Main
testtrace Information: 0 : Doing work for id 0
    LogicalOperationStack=0, Main
```

Notice how the output gives you a nested stack of logical operations. In this example, operation `0` was started in a separate thread.

Comment: According to the [.NET documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) the `EventLogTraceListener` does not obey the `TraceOutputOptions` property.